# Java abstract to treat two objects as the same in a tree

Tags: java, object, abstract

My assignment is to program a file system using folder objects and file objects, then to use a File System object to manage the two objects in the same tree. My issue is that I can't figure out how to treat the two objects as the same.

The assignment says "You may find it helpful to have an abstract class that the file and folder inherit from, so that you can treat them alike." But I keep getting errors.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FileSys {

    private Node firstFolder;

    public void newFolder(String loc) {
        if (firstFolder == null) { // If there are no folders
            Node folder = new Folder(loc); 
            firstFolder = folder;
        }
        else { // If there are folders

            String s = loc; 
            String[] folders = s.split("\\\\"); // Each file/folder name is put into an array

            boolean found; // Flag if found

            Node current = firstFolder; //Sets the first folder to the current
            int n = 0;

            while (folders.length - 1 > n) { // To find the folder being added to

                int i = 0;
                found = false; // Resets flag

                while (current.size > i) { // To search through the names of the folders

                    if (current.next[i].name.equalsIgnoreCase(folders[n])) {
                        current = current.next[i];
                        found = true; // Raises flag
                        break;
                    }

                    i++;
                }

                if ( !found) // incomplete. Add Exception.
                    System.out.println("ERROR");

                n++;
            }

            Node folder = new Folder(folders[folders.length - 1]);
            current.next[current.size] = folder;
        }
    }

    abstract class Node {
        String name;

        Node(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }



    private class File extends Node {
        String data;

        File(String nm, String data) {
            super(nm);
            this.data = data;
        }
    }


    private class Folder extends Node {
        private static final int ARRAYSIZE = 20; // default array size

        private int size = 0; 
        private Node[] next = new Node[ARRAYSIZE];

        public Folder(String nm) {
            super(nm);
            next[0] = null;
        }
    }

// Main method omitted
}
```

I appreciate any help in the right direction! I feel like it's an extremely simple mistake, but I don't have enough experience with objects and abstracts to know what's wrong. I've tried casting, but it leads to more errors during runtime. Thank you!

Edit:

```
    FileSys.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
                while(current.size > i)
                             ^
  symbol:   variable size
  location: variable current of type FileSys.Node
FileSys.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
                    if(current.next[i].name.equalsIgnoreCase(folders[n]))
                              ^
  symbol:   variable next
  location: variable current of type FileSys.Node
FileSys.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
                        current = current.next[i];
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable next
  location: variable current of type FileSys.Node
FileSys.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
            current.next[current.size] = folder;
                   ^
  symbol:   variable next
  location: variable current of type FileSys.Node
FileSys.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
            current.next[current.size] = folder;
                                ^
  symbol:   variable size
  location: variable current of type FileSys.Node
5 errors
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: What errors do you get? Your class setup makes sense.

Comment: I don't know how to treat two objects as alike. I made an abstract Node class but whenever I use  Node folder = new Folder(); I can't use any of the data located in the Folder object, such as next or size.

Comment: First and foremost, it's a matter of planning. The code itself can only start after you thoroughly planned your classes. First, a file system is a tree. So you need to think of a node as something that has its own properties (like a name or a size), and then has a number of children (not "next", because what's "next" in a tree?). What kind of operations are needed to traverse the tree? Then try to think of both a folder and a file as nodes, and think how each of them would implement the operations you figured out you needed, and then what makes them different from each other.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks! I made a few changes after becoming one with the newFolder method on paper. Made me realize I should just start with Folder firstFolder instead of Node firstFolder. From there I just changed all the Node variables to Folder and newFolder() is working pretty well now. I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 1):

When declare a variable as a class, you can only call it with methods defined for that class.

```
Node n = new Folder();
n.name; //Fine, all nodes have the name attribute
n.next; //Not fine, nodes do not have a next attribute
```

The solution is **type casting**. Type casting is a way of telling the compiler, "I know that this object will be of this type at runtime".

```
Folder f = (Folder) n; //We are telling the compiler that n is a Folder
f.next; //Fine, because folders have the next attribute
```

There is one last problem: we need to differentiate between folders and files. We can use the **instanceof** operator.

```
if(n instanceof Folder){
    doFolderStuff();
}else if (n instanceof File){
    doFileStuff()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using type casting in the wrong places before. Realized I mainly needed it when using pointers such as "current = (Folder)current.children[i];"

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing `current.size` and `current.next`. Both `size`and `next` are `private` in `Folder` class. It means you cannot access them using instances, they are `private` to the class and should be used internally by the class.

So, in order to access them use getters defined with `public` access specifier in your class something like

```
public int getSize() {
    //return size;
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as organisation is concerned you may want to unify object contracts you find similar:

```
public interface FSFilter{
  public boolean accept(FSNode node);
}

public interface FSNode {
  public String getPath();
  public FSNode getParent():
  public Volume getVolume();
  public boolean isFile();
  public boolean isFolder();
  public boolean isVolume();
  public boolean exists();
  public boolean delete();
  public List<FSNode> getSubNodes(boolean recursive, int depth, FSFilter filter);
  public int deleteSubNodes(boolean recursive, int depth, FSFilter filter);
  public long getSize(boolean recursive, int depth, FSFilter filter);
}
```

The above methods with different combinations of parameters would provide most of operations one may want from a file system tree. To add specific functions to specific types of File system objects, you can provide implementations for each. For example `Volume` class may have an extra `diskUsage()` method, and `File` class may have `getInputStream()` etc.

```
public class File implements FSNode { //... implementation...//}

public class Folder implements FSNode { //... implementation...//}

public class Volume implements FSNode { //... implementation...//}
```

Then, you may want to place all the utility logic that applies on all of these as a stateless static function, like recursive listing of files, deletion, creation and modifications. Because these operations would usually deal with underlying OS calls. These would be equivalents of OS commands like `ls`,`rm`, `mount` etc, in your program. The above implementations would be calling these utility functions internally. Also, most of the complex file system code would reside here:

```
public final class FSUtil{
  public static List<FSNode> list(boolean recursive, int depth, FSFilter filter){//... logic...//}
  public static long byteSize(FSNode node, boolean recursive, depth, FSFilter filter){//... logic...//}
  public static boolean delete(FSNode node,boolean recursive, FSFilter filter){//... logic...//}
  ... and more ...
}
```

For reference, you can look at existing implementations like [apache.commons.io](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/io/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/io/).